# Sequelize.js - build SQL query without executing it

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Is there a way to get Sequelize to build a query with the replacements (so I'll be able to use their SQL injection cleanup) and just get the raw SQL query, without executing it?

Answer (score 4):

You can just call the `QueryGenerator` with the type of query you want to generate.
For example a `selectQuery`:

```js
    const sql = MyModel.QueryGenerator.selectQuery(
        MyModel.getTableName(), {
        where: {
            someAttribute: "value"
        },
        attributes: ["other", "attributes"]
    },
        MyModel);
```

There's also `insertQuery`, `updateQuery`, `deleteQuery` too.

Comment: Might also be `MyModel.queryGenerator`.

Comment: I had to use `Utils.mapFinderOptions(queryOptions, MyModel)` for Sequelize to transform field names to db column names.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this feature isn't implemented yet, but there are some users trying to push the issue forward.

See [github issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2325).

Answer (score 2):

it's undocumented, but I use next way (Sequelize ver. 5.2.13):

```
let tableName = myModel.getTableName(options);
let qi = myModel.QueryInterface;
options.type = 'SELECT';
options.model = myModel;
var sql = qi.QueryGenerator.selectQuery(tableName, options, myModel);
```